# CPU spec for VPS hosting

Tags: vps, cpu-usage

I'm looking at various VPS hosting providers, and I notice that while many of them will give you the spec of the VPS in terms of how much RAM, hard disk space and bandwidth you will be provided, very few will give you how much CPU resource you will have available.

I'm curious about this, because there ARE some hosting providers (e.g. myhosting.com) that let you specify how many CPU resources you can have in your VPS (typically, this is done in terms of total MHz).

So does this mean that where the CPU spec for the VPS is not specified, it gets to use the entire CPU processing ability of the physical server that it is based  on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it really doesn't, it just means they're not telling you - nothing more, nothing less - they may buy all manner of CPUs and they don't want to commit to giving you one specific make/model.